# How to use transformers.Trainer on Windows without conda?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-trainer

I am trying to use the Trainer class from transformers module on Windows 10, python 3.10 and CUDA 12.1 and *all modules installed using* **pip**.

nvcc --version :

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Feb__8_05:53:42_Coordinated_Universal_Time_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.1, V12.1.66
Build cuda_12.1.r12.1/compiler.32415258_0
```

cuda available:

```
torch.cuda.is_available() #True
```

But when I tried to import Trainer:

```
from transformers import Trainer
```

I got a huge log error:

```
CUDA_SETUP: WARNING! libcudart.so not found in any environmental path. Searching in backup paths...
The following directories listed in your path were found to be non-existent: {WindowsPath('/usr/local/cuda/lib64')}
DEBUG: Possible options found for libcudart.so: set()
CUDA SETUP: PyTorch settings found: CUDA_VERSION=121, Highest Compute Capability: 8.6.
CUDA SETUP: To manually override the PyTorch CUDA version please see:https://github.com/TimDettmers/bitsandbytes/blob/main/how_to_use_nonpytorch_cuda.md
CUDA SETUP: Loading binary D:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\bitsandbytes\libbitsandbytes_cuda121.so...
argument of type 'WindowsPath' is not iterable
CUDA SETUP: Problem: The main issue seems to be that the main CUDA runtime library was not detected.
CUDA SETUP: Solution 1: To solve the issue the libcudart.so location needs to be added to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable
CUDA SETUP: Solution 1a): Find the cuda runtime library via: find / -name libcudart.so 2>/dev/null
CUDA SETUP: Solution 1b): Once the library is found add it to the LD_LIBRARY_PATH: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:FOUND_PATH_FROM_1a
CUDA SETUP: Solution 1c): For a permanent solution add the export from 1b into your .bashrc file, located at ~/.bashrc
CUDA SETUP: Solution 2: If no library was found in step 1a) you need to install CUDA.
CUDA SETUP: Solution 2a): Download CUDA install script: wget https://github.com/TimDettmers/bitsandbytes/blob/main/cuda_install.sh
CUDA SETUP: Solution 2b): Install desired CUDA version to desired location. The syntax is bash cuda_install.sh CUDA_VERSION PATH_TO_INSTALL_INTO.
CUDA SETUP: Solution 2b): For example, "bash cuda_install.sh 113 ~/local/" will download CUDA 11.3 and install into the folder ~/local
```

and

```
RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.trainer because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):

        CUDA Setup failed despite GPU being available. Please run the following command to get more information:

        python -m bitsandbytes

        Inspect the output of the command and see if you can locate CUDA libraries. You might need to add them
        to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH. If you suspect a bug, please take the information from python -m bitsandbytes
        and open an issue at: https://github.com/TimDettmers/bitsandbytes/issues
```

Trying to debug the **bitsandbytes** *.py files, on cuda_setups, there is a module called "env_vars":

https://github.com/TimDettmers/bitsandbytes/blob/main/bitsandbytes/cuda_setup/env_vars.py

Apparently it would only work with conda, is that right?

So is there any workaround to make this work?

Comment: 1) you have nvidia gpu on the machine you are installing to ? 2) you have installed cuda drivers ? 3) dunno if this is relevant but is CUDA_HOME environment variable set  ?

Comment: 1) yes 2) yes as I said: cuda version 12.1 3) yes

Comment: Any luck? I can't get bitsandbytes to run on Windows either - I get `libbitsandbytes_cuda121.so is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error`.